# IE 8 Render issues?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, rendering, margin, padding

I need some guide here about ie 8 rendering? (not sure how to phrase it). Here is the problem,
I have coded aspx and I have test on multiple browser and pc. It work prefectly fine. How I test for IE.

I pressed f12 and change the mode to ie8. It work prefectly fine on multiple computer. Till my client should be his laptop using ie8 and I saw all my items shift to the left side.

First I would like to know how can I test it. Since, my computer display completely fine?
Second, is there a reasons for different rendering?

I saw people said about meta tag. But I cant test it that is the problem. If meta tag is the solution. Does older pc support it?

The structure how I code my website only padding.
I only use margin if i want to align my div to the center which is margin: 0 auto. Other than that there is nothing special about my website.

Comment: You can donwload an image from [msdn](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11575) that you can run in VirtualPC to have a real IE8 instead of an emulated one. Also provide the smallest sample of html markup and css that demonstrates the problem

Comment: Hi, I tried to install but the ie on harddisk image is not firing

Comment: You can ask a question about that problem on superuser.com. You did install Virtual PC as well?

Answer (score 0):

I've found IE Tester an easy way to test multiple versions of IE - but you will have to upload the files to a server in order to view it since you will need to enter the URL to test.

Here is where you can find IE Tester: http://www.my-debugbar.com/ietester/?version=0.4.11 (it's free)